# Python - Using same randint value in different functions within class object

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, random

I'm quite new in programming and as an exercise, I wanted to try writing a very basic game.

I will not choke you in details. Let me explain where I'm having trouble.
There are 2 players shooting each other. Each turn they spend random amount of bullets between (1,10) and damage the other, and whoever reaches 0 health loses the game.

Right now, I can call random bullet number to shoot the other player. But I want the damage to be related with the amount of bullet used. For example if player1 used 5 bullets that turn, player2 will be damaged 5*10, or if 2 then damaged 2*10 and etc.

And here is my code. I appreciate any kind of help. Thanks!

```
import random

bullet_spent = random.randrange(1,10)
damage = bullet_spent * 10

# Enemy object
class Enemy():

    def __init__(self,name,hp,ammo):
        self.name = name
        self.hp = hp
        self.ammo = ammo

# Defined actions    
    def attack(self):
        bullet_spent = random.randrange(1,10)
        print(self.name + " Shoots. " + str(bullet_spent) + " bullets spent.")
        self.ammo -= bullet_spent  

    def be_damaged(self):
        damage = bullet_spent * 10
        self.hp -= damage
        print(self.name + " lost " + str(damage) + " HP.")
        print("Remaining HP: " + str(self.hp))

# Enemy list
player1 = Enemy("Player1",100,50)
player2 = Enemy("Player2",100,50)
```

Comment: You have two *entirely unrelated* variables named `bullet_spent` here - a local variable in `attack()` that gets deducted from `self.ammo`, but not otherwise used (or even available to be used) for anything, and a global variable that's set once at the start of the code and never changed again (this is what's being used in `be_damaged()`).

Comment: You also are deducting bullets and HP without checking availability.  The number of bullets shot, for example, should be the minimum of your random number and the amount of ammo remaining.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

What would you suggest me about being able to use the same randint number from attack() and put it inside be_damaged() function in a way that the number will act *10 of that number?

Comment: Does one fighter get to take all of their shots before the other, is it a coin toss who gets the next shot, or do they alternate shots until one of them has HP take down to zero?

Comment: @pjs It's turn based. p1 attacks p2, and then p2 attacks p1 until one of them reaches 0 hp. They both have 50 ammo at the start. And they spend random amount of bullets each turn btw (1,10). But the damage will be amount of bullet spent*10.

Comment: So think about what you described.  My HP gets reduced by my enemy's shooting, and vice-versa, while my bullets are reduced by my shooting.  Shooting should be directed at a specific enemy, should deduct the ammo from my inventory, and should "notify" them how much damage they've suffered based on my shooting.  An enemy notifying me that I've been shot should specify how much damage they've inflicted, and I should reduce my HP accordingly.  Your "main" should be able to query HP after each round, and declare a winner.  Organize your code accordingly.

Comment: use `return bullet_spent` in `attack()` and use `spent` in `def be_damaged(self, spent)` and run it as `spent = p1.attack()` and then `p2.be_damaged(spent)` or directly `p2.be_damaged(p1.attack())` (if player1 shoot faster then player2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `return bullet_spent` in `attack()`

```
def attack(self):

    # rest

    return bullet_spent
```

and `bullet_spent` as argument in `be_damaged()`

```
def be_damaged(self, bullet_spent):  

    # rest
```

and then you can do get value from one player to another

```
spend1 = p1.attack()
spend2 = p2.attack()

p1.be_damaged(spend2)
p2.be_damaged(spend1)
```